# Setting process affinity in Linux

Tags: linux, process, multi-core, affinity

In Windows, it is possible to make a program run on any number of cores in a multicore processor. It can be set in the Task Manager GUI.

Likewise, Is it possible to set the process affinity in Linux, on the command line? To specify what cores the process can run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Debian package manager schedtool can do it. (However, it is a command line tool)

Don't know of any GUI tools.

This article http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6799 indicates that Linux was late to the game of setting cpu affinity. Also with 2.5 kernels and newer, the ping pong effect is not present, processes tend to stay on the same cpu. Therefore setting CPU affinity MAY not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

htop can do it if you press 'a' then choose from the list of CPUs